# PIN selecting problem over arduino

Tags: arduino, schematics, programming, multiplexer

My schematic as below. I  have connected 8 hall sensor as shown in picture. Problem i am facing here is SO, s1, s2 The Led light are not glowing .Even the forard voltage across is 3.9v. i have tested with multimeter LED working fine. Please let me know why might be reason to not glow when upload below code.

SO,S1,S2 are selective pins for MUX IC. Here i am scaling up to 24 after that. I found The digital Io across are getting properly as per truth table or array mentioned.

```
#include <avr/wdt.h>
int SO_enable=7;
int S1_enable=6;
int S2_enable=5;
int Enablepin=4;
int Sensor_Value0=0;
int Sensor_Value1=0;
int Sensor_Value2=0;
float  voltage0;
float voltage1;

float Current_Mux1[9];
float Current_Mux2[9];
float Current_Mux3[9];
float ARDUINO_ANALOG_SCALING=0.004799608993157;
int row,column;
int DigitalHigh=8;
int DigitalHigh1=9;
static float  Mux1_array[9]={
  0.0};
static float  Mux2_array[9]={
  0.0};
  static float  Mux3_array[9]={
  0.0};

 float Current_Value1[9]={0.0};
 float Current_Value2[9]={0.0};
int array[9][4]={
  {    0,0,0,0  }
  ,
  {    0,0,0,1  }
  ,
  {    0,0,1,0  }
  ,  
  {    0,0,1,1  }
  ,
  {    0,1,0,0  }
  ,
  {    0,1,0,1  }
  ,
  {    0,1,1,0  }
  ,
  {    0,1,1,1  }
  ,
  {    1,0,0,0  }

};

void setup()
{
  wdt_enable(WDTO_8S);
  pinMode(SO_enable, OUTPUT) ;// pin can enable/disable using digital IO 7 of arduino
  pinMode(S1_enable, OUTPUT) ;// pin can enable/disable using digital IO 6 of arduino
  pinMode(S2_enable, OUTPUT) ;// pin can enable/disable using digital IO 5 of arduino
  pinMode(Enablepin, OUTPUT) ;// pin can enable/disable using digital IO 4 of arduino
  pinMode(A0, INPUT) ;
  pinMode(A5, INPUT) ;
  pinMode(DigitalHigh,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(DigitalHigh1,OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print("Channel\t");
 Serial.print("MUX1_V \t"); Serial.print("MUX1_C \t");
   Serial.print("MUX2_V \t"); Serial.print("MUX2_C \t");
   Serial.print("MUX3_V \t"); Serial.println("MUX3_C \t");
}

void loop()
{
  wdt_reset();
  digitalWrite(DigitalHigh,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(DigitalHigh1,HIGH);
  for(row=0;row<9;row++)
  {
    int k=(8*array[row][0]+4*array[row][1]+2*array[row][2]+1*array[row][3]);

   // Serial.print("k:");
    Serial.print(k);
    Serial.print("\t");
    digitalWrite(Enablepin,array[row][0]);
    digitalWrite(SO_enable,array[row][1]);
    digitalWrite(S1_enable,array[row][2]);
    digitalWrite(S2_enable,array[row][3]); 
   delay(100); 
    Sensor_Value0=analogRead(A0);
    Sensor_Value1=analogRead(A5);
    Sensor_Value2=analogRead(A3);

   Mux1_array[row]=(Sensor_Value0 * ARDUINO_ANALOG_SCALING);
   Mux2_array[row]=(Sensor_Value1 * ARDUINO_ANALOG_SCALING);
   Mux3_array[row]=(Sensor_Value2 * ARDUINO_ANALOG_SCALING);
    Current_Mux1[row] = (Mux1_array[row]*35.1428571429)-87.6571428571;
    Current_Mux2[row]=(Mux2_array[row]*35.1428571429)-87.6571428571;
    Current_Mux3[row]=(Mux3_array[row]*35.1428571429)-87.6571428571;

  Serial.print( Mux1_array[row]);Serial.print("\t");Serial.print( Current_Mux1[row]);Serial.print("\t");
Serial.print( Mux2_array[row]);Serial.print("\t");Serial.print( Current_Mux2[row]);Serial.print("\t");
Serial.print( Mux3_array[row]);Serial.print("\t");Serial.println( Current_Mux3[row]);


  }
 Serial.println("...................................................................");
 Serial.print("Channel\t");
 Serial.print("MUX1_V \t"); Serial.print("MUX1_C \t");
   Serial.print("MUX2_V \t"); Serial.print("MUX2_C \t");
   Serial.print("MUX3_V \t"); Serial.println("MUX3_C \t");
 delay(500);
}
```

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjEywe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

From the CD74HCT4051 datasheet:

> I<sub>IL</sub> (Control input leakage current): ±0.1μA

Err... that's not going to light up the LED. Unless you have superhuman vision. Put the LED in parallel with the MUX instead.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNvOHT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>